# Using a CSS class, but can't find where it is defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been searching for an easy way to make a month/year picker for an ASP.NET Core application I'm making.  I found this [fantastic](https://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/k5zookLt/20/) one on jsfiddle.  It uses the following resources:

- [bootstrap-datepicker.min.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js)
- [datepicker.min.css](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.min.css)
- [bootstrap.min.js](https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js)
- [bootstrap.min.css](https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css)

Here is the code:

```js
var startDate = new Date();
var fechaFin = new Date();
var FromEndDate = new Date();
var ToEndDate = new Date();

$('.from').datepicker({
  autoclose: true,
  minViewMode: 1,
  format: 'mm/yyyy'
}).on('changeDate', function(selected) {
  startDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
  startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate(new Date(selected.date.valueOf())));
  $('.to').datepicker('setStartDate', startDate);
});

$('.to').datepicker({
  autoclose: true,
  minViewMode: 1,
  format: 'mm/yyyy'
}).on('changeDate', function(selected) {
  FromEndDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
  FromEndDate.setDate(FromEndDate.getDate(new Date(selected.date.valueOf())));
  $('.from').datepicker('setEndDate', FromEndDate);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>First check in:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-1 input-sm from" placeholder="CheckIn">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>First check out:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-2 input-sm to" placeholder="CheckOut">
</div>

<br/>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Second check in:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-1 input-sm from" placeholder="CheckIn">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Second check out:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-2 input-sm to" placeholder="CheckOut">
</div>
```

I have made this work in my project in Visual Studio, however, it doesn't seem to be able to find the classes "form-control-1" (and 2) and "from" and so it gives me a little squiggly line indicating so.

[image]

I started looking through all the css files included and I cannot find a reference to those classes in any file.  If I remove them, the month selector does not work.  Can someone help me understand where that functionality is coming from?  Does anyone know where those classes are defined?

Comment: My guess is the javascript will be using those for either styling from within the js or targeting the inputs with it

Comment: but I should be able to find that string in the .js file though?  Or am I wrong?  I looked and I don't see those strings anywhere in the .js files.

Comment: The `from` and `to` are not being used for styling, they are being used in the code that you posted. `$('.from').datepicker()` `$('.to').datepicker()`

Comment: CSS classes DO NOT have to be in the stylesheet, some are used just as a key to look up things.

Comment: Just ignore the squiggly highlighting

Comment: @luisenrike that does explain the "from", thank you.

Comment: You can safely delete the `form-control-1` and `form-control-2` classes

Comment: @luisenrike put both of your statements in an answer and I'll select it as the correct answer.  You have been most helpful, thank you.

Comment: Done ;) .......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `from` and `to` are not being used for styling, they are being used in the code that you posted. `$('.from').datepicker()` `$('.to').datepicker()`.

You can safely delete the `form-control-1` and `form-control-2` classes.

Answer (score 0):

Those classes can be fuctional classes, not attached to any styling but used to select or manipulate the elements.

Thats probably why you wont find anything. Search through the js files and you will find something.

Comment: in jquery you have this line: ```$('.from').datepicker('setEndDate', FromEndDate);```

Answer (score 0):

Since removing the class breaks the functionality, it's probably being referenced from JS. It may be that the JS is calculating the name of the class, something like `"form-control " + i` for example.

Your best bet to see where this is defined is to use the browser inspector. For example, in Chrome, right-click the page and choose "inspect" to get this UI, which shows you each css class and where they are declared or re-declared in the css hierarchy. [image: class inspector for this page]

Answer (score 0):

When using Javascript it can be very useful to use CSS classes which are not attached to any styling, but are instead used as *semantic* references for jQuery selectors to use later.

This can be very useful when trying to attach multiple semantic meanings to an element. You can have one element can have many semantic tags. I use this in complex components to be able to dynamically tag elements that I can later manipulate or check the class name. *This is especially useful if you are generating elements from a server-side language and trying to tag them semantically so that they can be manipulated later from Javascript/jQuery.* It think it is much easier to add a dynamic class string from the server side than to put in data attributes.

One example of this that I use is for validation information to be attached to an element. I generate the elements in a server-side class (including what type of validation it should have) which outputs a CSS class string, then when I submit the form in Javascript, I get all elements with specific classnames and check if their contents match the validation type.

The code sample you posted does a similar thing, where it wants to use a jQuery plugin on all elements with a certain class. Instead of direct styling, it uses them as semantic markers that those elements should be transformed in a certain way to be datepickers (which are documented here: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/). Code for jQueryUI uses this a lot to be able to simplify which elements should be used-- and it can be easier to add new elements that are datepickers, since you simply add a class to the new one instead of having to add a new jQuery reference to it (especially if you don't know exactly how many of them there will be on the page when you write the Javscipt code).

If you are ever in a similar instance and looking for a different way to store data on elements without inadvertent effects and it is pure Javascript without server side rendering, data-* attributes in HTML5 are a way to do it (and a simple library could be developed to add them to elements from a server side language). Just use jQuery selectors with `jQuery("[data-mytagname=someValue]")` to select.

**A word of caution** that if you use classes like this as semantic tags, I would be careful to avoid commonly used class names, since you could inadvertently get extra styling when a co-worker (or yourself) decides to use that in an element. ;)